# Probability density functions (normal distribution)

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, density-function

I was trying out some probability questions when I came upon this one that I'm perplexed by;

> Let $X \sim  N(0,1)$ and $Y = e^X.$  Find the density function of $Y$.

I know the density function for $N(\mu, \sigma 2)$ is $$f(x) =
\frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}} \exp\left(−\frac{(x−\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right).$$

Is this the function that i use? and how do I find the density function in terms of $Y?$

Comment: Please use MathJax (or at least unambiguous notation): $\quad eX=e^X$ or $e\cdot X ?$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pdf of a random variable can be found by using its cdf.
Let consider
\begin{equation}
\textbf{P}(Y \le x) = \textbf{P}(\exp(X) \le x) = \textbf{P}(X \le \log x)
\end{equation}
Since 
$$ \textbf{P}(X \le \log x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\log x} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}e^{-\frac{(t-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}dt $$
by differentiating with $x$, we obtain
$$ f_Y(x)
 = \frac{d\mathbf{P}(Y\le x)}{x}
 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma x}\exp\left(-\frac{(\log x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)$$

Comment: how come it is log(X) instead of Ln(X)

Comment: @fjl123 It is the same  :) what I meant was.